# GroupBy column using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to group by datatable using followng method. However i can not select a column which includes string

```
var dtTAConvertList =
    (from dr1 in dtTAConvert.AsEnumerable()
     group dr1 by dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") into g
     select new
     {
         SAMPLE_TIME = g.Key,
         WAIT_CLASS = g.Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS"),          // ==> I get error in this line
         COUNT = Math.Round(g.Sum(h => h.Field<double>("COUNT")) / 15.0, 2),
     });
```

It throws the exception

> 'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and the best extension method overload 'DataRowExtensions.Field(DataRow, string)' requires a receiver of type 'DataRow'

How can  i select string column that already exist in that datatable?

Comment: Can you include the error message in your question, please?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes edited question.

Comment: use `g` instead `dr1`

Comment: @MaciejS. edited question.

Comment: 'g' is a collection/range variable. Do you want the 'First()'?

Comment: @Silvermind Didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: Use g.First().Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have many occurrences of `Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS")` per group, you will have to proceed much the same way as for the counting, except that you probably want to retrieve the first occurrence:

```
var dtTAConvertList =
    (from dr1 in dtTAConvert.AsEnumerable()
     group dr1 by dr1.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") into g
     select new {
         SAMPLE_TIME = g.Key,
         WAIT_CLASS = g.First().Field<string>("WAIT_CLASS"),
         COUNT = Math.Round(g.Sum(h => h.Field<double>("COUNT")) / 15.0, 2),
     });
```

Comment: The problem with using 'first()' is, just getting the first element. Which is totally false. I just want to group by string column using sample time.

Comment: If you group by `SAMPLE_TIME` and have several records with with the same sample time, then this group will contain this `SAMPLE_TIME` as key and an enumeration of the records belonging to this key. I.e., you will have several `WAIT_CLASS` entries to choose from per SAMPLE_TIME. You can choose Max, Min, First, Sum, etc. Another option is to group per `SAMPLE_TIME` and `WAIT_CLASS`. You did not specify what should happen in this case.